# GitHub Travic-Ci Build Failed After Pull Request

Tags: github, travis-ci, puredata

I made a very minor tweak to a PureData file causing an issue and submitted a pull request to fix this. There are no branch conflicts and everything works correctly, however I've stumbled upon a "Travic CI build failed" error. The log for this error is below. Anybody have any idea why this fails?

[Failed Travis-CI Build Log](https://travis-ci.org/balandinodidonato/MyoMapper/jobs/269868144)

Comment: The log has an error message. I suggest you google it to learn how to fix it.

Comment: Hey [Jefferson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4479585/jefferson) , check this [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8106/trying-to-understand-what-travis-ci-does-and-when-it-should-be-used),really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your project includes no `.travis.yml` in its source root directory. Therefore travis tries to build a default ruby project. This fails because yours' is not a default ruby project.